# Schedule a bq command line in GCP

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a command line that I execute to import backups from GCS into BigQuery:

bq load --replace --source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP firestore_exports.raw2 gs://testbucket/2019/all_namespaces/kind_Rates/all_namespaces_kind_Rates.export_metadata

**Is there a way I can schedule this job? I dont want to do it manually.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's called: [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/)

as it only supports:

Specify the target:

- Pub/Sub
- App Engine HTTP
- HTTP

You may need to either change this line in a Google Cloud Function that can be hit by HTTP, or build a [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) container to run your command line shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can create scheduled transfer jobs with [Cloud Storage transfers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer).